# Accessing Instance Variables with array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, methods

I have a java object with these attributes and methods:

```
public class Student {
    private String name; 
    private String surname;
    private int age;
    private int[] qualifications = new int[4];
}

public Student(String name, String surname, int age, int[] qualifications){
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.age = age;
    this.qualifications = qualifications;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int[] getQualifications () {
    return qualifications;
}

public void setQualifications(int[] qualifications) {
    this. qualifications = qualifications;
}
```

I initialize an instance of the object with:

```
Student a1 = new Student("John","Doe",32,new int[]{10,8,9,9});
```

and I try to get and set the name and the qualifications. With name attribute works, but it doesn't work with array of qualifications.

```
// it works
a1.setName("Tom");
System.out.println("Name of the student: "+a1.getName());


//it doesn't work
System.out.println("Qualifications of the student: "+a1.getQualifications());

//return:
[I@15db9742
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Arrays.toString(a1.getQualifications())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "doesn't work" you mean you get an output like:

> Qualifications of the student: [I@368102c8

Then the "fix" is to use `Arrays.toString` to print the array:

```
System.out.println("Qualifications of the student: " + Arrays.toString(a1.getQualifications());
```

This will output:

> Qualifications of the student: [10, 8, 9, 9]

If you want to get rid of the enclosing `[...]`,
then use `String.substring`, for example:

```
String arrstr = Arrays.toString(a1.getQualifications());
System.out.println("Qualifications of the student: " + arrstr.substring(1, arrstr.length() - 1));
```

This will output:

> Qualifications of the student: 10, 8, 9, 9

Answer (score 0):

To print the elements of Array you'd use `Arrays.toString(array)`, `a1.getQualifications()` will return the default implementation of `toString` method